# DataGridTextColumn foreground [Theme Resoruce] does not change in dark mode

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, foreground, datagridtextcolumn

Using "ThemeResource" I want to change the foreground depending on whether it is in light mode or dark mode

But it only works in Light mode, in dark mode use the default color

**DataGridTextColumn**

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource GrayTextColor}" />
  </Style>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayTextColor" Color="#99000000" />
              </ResourceDictionary>

<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayTextColor" Color="#99FFFFFF" />
              </ResourceDictionary>
```

I've already tried "white" / "black" and opacity 0.6, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Hi, I tested this problem and it does exist, but it has nothing to do with a specific theme. If the initial theme of the application is `ApplicationTheme.Dark`, then when the `Page.RequestTheme` is switched to `ElementTheme.Light`, the control will not respond to the change of the theme. I noticed that you have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3402) on Github, and the engineer will test this issue and respond positively, Thanks.

Comment: I understand, thanks for responding